# string.Format on my regex is giving me spaces in place of curly braces?

Tags: c#, regex

My regex after a String.Format(c#):

> (^{0})|({0}[-!#$%&'}()*+,./:;<=>?@_`\{{|~"])|([-!#$%&'()*+,./}:;<=>?@_`{|~"]{0})|( {0} )

When the regex is coming through the debugger it looks like this:

> (^ Word )|( Word [-!#$%&'}()*+,./:;<=>?@_`\{|~"])|([-!#$%&'()*+,./}:;<=>?@_`{|~"] Word )|(  Word )

The curly braces for my string.format have been replaced with spaces, which obviously breaks my regex. Does anyone know how to solve this problem??

Comment: Are you 100% sure there are no spaces around the string you are passing to string.Format?

Comment: Could you please post a code snippet? the behavior you are describing is too strange, you are probably making a simple mistake...

Comment: Yes, could you add the complete string.format call?

Answer (score 4):

String.Format does not add spaces when it substitutes the value in.  My guess is your word is the culprit.  Where does it come from?  Have you tried trimming it before the format call?

```
public Regex getExpression(string word)
{
    string baseExpr = @"(^{0})|({0}[-!#$%&'}()+,./:;<=>?@\{{|~""])|([-!#$%&'()*+,./}:;<=>?@_{|~""]{0})|( {0} )";

    return new Regex(string.Format(baseExpr, word.Trim()));
}
```

You may want to sanitize the word even more to strip out key regex characters.

Comment: Your code sample crashes with a FormatException in the string.Format() call.

Comment: I just copied his expression verbatim and added " characters to the syntax highlighting works.  Looks like he didn't escape all the { characters correctly.

Comment: to "sanitize" the word I'd suggest to use at least Regex.Escape() because otherwise you have a "regex injection" possibility ;)